# Why does my apache2 Website domain get resolved to my external ip address of my network?

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, dyndns

I have my DynDNS activated on my router and Domain-Host and did portforwarding to my raspberry pi, where I host a website via apache2. Now If I load my Website over my domain, everything works out, but the domain in the address bar gets resolved into the IP-Address of my router. Does someone now how to fix this problem? I have looked for ages and couldnt find anything?

Comment: if your router does not get public IP address from ISP then no port forwarding will help you - no one from Internet can connect to the host which has private IP address (I mean your router).

Comment: No - I am able to load the website. The unly thing I'm struggling with is, that in the address bar if I type in my domain.xyz it changes to the ip. (This problem does not occur, if I call the website via Chrome inkognito.

Do you understand my problem?

Comment: most likely your apache or code does redirect but I'm puzzled at how it would know its external IP address. I would expect such redirect happen in case your virtual host's ServerName  does not match domain.xyz and you query index of sub-folder without enclosing slash "/". Without knowing your domain name and your code hosted by apache my bets are off. If you are willing to share your domain name then please do. You can contact me directly in case you do not want to share it in public.